# Unable to read PDF using tablea

Tags: python, tabula

Name: tabula-py
Version: 2.1.1
Python: 3.8.1
Java: 8.251

I am unable to read the PDF using below code.

```
from tabula import read_pdf_with_template, read_pdf

filePath = "FilePath/sample.pdf"
df = read_pdf(filePath)

print(df)
```

**Execution Message:-**

```
'pages' argument isn't specified.Will extract only from page 1 by default.
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Pdf Source:**

```
http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
```

Could someone help why pdf is not read?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try reading the PDF file this way but first, of all your should pip install tabula-py. Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java` then it would work.

```
import tabula
pdf_path = "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, stream=True)
```

Comment: Having all pre-condition and added 'stream=True' but getting the same result.

Comment: Also, I have created a sample PDF file for testing and that worked perfectly fine. Not sure why the pdf that I downloaded from the path 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'  is not working.

Comment: Well, I think your PDF file is just a raw textfile and the tabula module is a wrapper of tabula, which enables extract tables from PDF  into pandas DataFrame. Currently, the implementation of this module uses a subprocess. my guess is that you need a pdf file with tables to be able to enable you to read. so I guess  you need to try with a PDF with tables since this one is just plain text . and that's why you keep getting this output ....'pages' argument isn't specified.Will extract only from page 1 by default.
[]

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

tabula-py is a Python package to extract tables from PDF, which extracts tables by using some heuristics.

Your example PDF consists of just raw text, so you need to use other packages to read PDF like [PyPDF](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/).